# Google map travel mode to cross sea

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently able to calculate the distance by land. using Distance Matrix, but I can't calculate once the sea is encountered. My markers disappear.

Example : 
[image]

Once I've searched for Guimaras my markers would disappear. I know this happens because I'm using
travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
Is there a travel mode that will cross the sea?

Comment: so, how would you get a car to the island? is there a ferry service?

Comment: @JaromandaX no, It's not important. I've just used it to calculate the distance from the **origin**. We know cars won't work on the sea so I'm looking for an alternative way to get the distance.

Comment: distance? straight line distance is easy if you have the co-ordinates of the two points - don't even need google maps

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I know that. Mine is more on comparing **origin** marker from multiple addresses, which is working fine as you could see on the map. It's even showing the distance. The only problem is if the marker is from the other island or continent It won't calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, this feature is not available. The best thing you can do about this is to file a **Feature Request** in [Google Issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)

If you really need this now, a work around to get the distance of 2 places (separated by water area) that I can suggest is by doing 2 separate requests and then adding the returns them later. *(I can only give you an idea but this is incomplete)*

You can just manually create a functionality that would calculate the distance from your origin to the nearest port. We can use [Iloilo City](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Iloilo+City,+Iloilo/@10.7042321,122.5627904,15z/data=!4m21!1m15!4m14!1m6!1m2!1s0x33aee56fe538d781:0xe8250cd6bc30a488!2sIloilo+City,+Iloilo!2m2!1d122.5621063!2d10.7201501!1m6!1m2!1s0x33aee57f52546a07:0xbfc18e23fb7bee1b!2sIloilo+Domestic+Port,+Fort+San+Pedro+Dr,+Iloilo+City+Proper,+Iloilo+City,+5000+Iloilo!2m2!1d122.5822951!2d10.6902944!3m4!1s0x33aee56fe538d781:0xe8250cd6bc30a488!8m2!3d10.7201501!4d122.5621063) as the example of origin and the ferry station is [Iloilo Domestic Port](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Iloilo+Domestic+Port/@10.6844859,122.6003127,13.58z/data=!4m21!1m15!4m14!1m6!1m2!1s0x33aee57f52546a07:0xbfc18e23fb7bee1b!2sIloilo+Domestic+Port,+Fort+San+Pedro+Dr,+Iloilo+City+Proper,+Iloilo+City,+5000+Iloilo!2m2!1d122.5822951!2d10.6902944!1m6!1m2!1s0x33aee5f101ef5ef7:0xa4d796d1ba3672ff!2sMacArthurs+Wharf+Ferry+Terminal,+Buenavista,+Guimaras!2m2!1d122.6130405!2d10.6886207!3m4!1s0x33aee57f52546a07:0xbfc18e23fb7bee1b!8m2!3d10.6902944!4d122.5822951). I got this by using [Places Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search). Here's the portion of the code with parameters that helped:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch({
  location: {lat: 10.72015, lng: 122.562106},
  radius: 5000,
  keyword: 'ferry',
  type: 'transit_station',
  rankby: 'popularity'
}, callback);
```

Then get the nearest port for [Guimaras](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Guimaras+Island/@10.5801091,122.460448,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x33aeec430d155993:0x4b66f916a792dc43!8m2!3d10.5843552!4d122.6051351) (your destination) which is [Jordan Guimaras Jetty Port](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Jordan+Guimaras+Jetty+Port/@10.675704,122.595238,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x6ac4f552d967e0d7!8m2!3d10.667031!4d122.58919?hl=en-US)

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch({
  //location: {lat: 10.72015, lng: 122.562106}, //iloilo
  location: {lat: 10.592866, lng: 122.632508}, //guimaras
  radius: 10000,
  keyword: 'port',
  type: 'transit_station',
  rankby: 'popularity'
}, callback);
```

> Note: The codes are not consistent due to the fact that it does not always return a result. Also, this may not work for some cases since the 'port/ferry' keyword is not always present in the radius.

Now that we have those 2 ports, we now can get the distance from Iloilo to the port, using the **Distance Matrix** then do another request from the next port to Guimaras. After doing so, you may now add the 2 results.

> Another downside of this is you don't get to calculate the distance from the first port to the next one. This will skip the water area and just calculate the land area.
>
> Please keep in mind that this is only my suggestion and maybe you could think of another option. And again, the best fix for this is to file a feature request in **[Google Issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/)**. Hope this helps. :)